# Matrices and vectors

Tags: linear-algebra

I am wondering if you can write a 2x2 matrix

$$\left(\begin{array}{cc} a & b \\ c & d\end{array}\right)$$

as a one vector

$$\left(\begin{array}{c} a \\ b \\ c \\ d\end{array}\right).$$

Comment: Yes, if that's helpful to you. (Notice that, for instance, the addition operation is essentially the same, but you can't multiply vectors, so you have to remember how the vector came from the matrix if you ever want to multiply them.)

Comment: [This](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vectorization_%28mathematics%29) might be helpful.

Comment: yes the edited version of the question is what i meant, thanks

Comment: I don't know why people are emphasizing the order in which the entries are placed so much. If you fix whatever method of taking the matrix entries and putting them into a vector, you get a perfectly sensible vector version of the matrix and vector addition and scaling will agree with the matrix addition and scaling. You *do* have to map all the matrices consistently though, you can't change schemes in the middle of things. The multiplication is pretty much lost though, and if you want to keep doing matrix multiplication, keep the squares.

Comment: After skimming the links a bit I see there is a little gain in computing some exotic matrix products. Still, it's worth seeing that you basically "can't go wrong" when turning the matrices into vectors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can do this in two ways:

1. Row-major Order
2. Column-major Order

They both allow you to write a matrix in linear/sequential manner. In the first one you do it as you explained in the example by writing first row first,then second one and so on. In the latter one, you do it by writing first column first, then second and so on.

Edit: A useful link might be: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Row-major_order

Answer (score 2):

As suggested in the comments, you might want to read about **[Vectorization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vectorization_%28mathematics%29)** of a matrix.

Note that to vectorize your two by two matrix, you can put the first column entries over the second *column* entries.

$\left(\begin{array}{cc} a & b \\ c & d\end{array}\right)$ can also be expressed as: $\begin{pmatrix} a \\ c \\ b \\ d\end{pmatrix}$

Doing so is compatible with (and defined for) some, but not all, matrix operations.

Comment: $+^{+_{+_{+_{+_{+_{+\to\infty}}}}}}$

Comment: @Babak: $*^{*_{*_{*_{*_{*_{*\to *}}}}}}$

Comment: Amy, what does the pronunciation of "Elizabeth" sound to you? Is it like "Els-beth" or "Eliza-beth"?? Thanks

Comment: Like "E-liz-a-beth" primary accent (emphasis) on the "liz" with "i" in "liz* pronounced as in "his" ("liz"  rhymes with "his")